# Case comment notification in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

When I am selecting Public and Send Case Notifications from System Address, when adding a case comment, mails are going through my own mail id i.e. logged in person email id, not from default email id. May I know how to configure to send notification through system mail id.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Setup -> App Setup -> Cases -> Support Settings and enable(check) the "Send Case Notifications from System Address" option.

> "Send Case Notifications from System Address" setting is used to to
>   specify that case comment, case attachment, and case assignment email
>   notifications are sent from a system address. If you do not select
>   this setting, case notifications will appear to be sent from the user
>   or contact updating the case.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Logged in user > My Settings(Left Panel) > Email > My Email Settings > Here change the email address

[image]

Now if the customer receives mail from this supporttest@abc.com mail id but the logged in user email id will be diffrent. Hope this helps